# How to update Data in tableview using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

Currently I have 3 swift files: ManualViewController, AutoViewController, Main

ManualViewController is the UIViewController with a table view.
AutoViewController is a UIViewController with a few buttons.
Main is just a swift file with all the data for table view.

ManualViewController and AutoViewController are controlled using TabBarController.

When I run the app the initial contents found in Main.swift is loaded onto the table view. When I go to the next view i.e AutoViewController and click on a button to change data in Main.swift, the data changes. The problem is when I switch back to ManualViewController the table still contains the old data and not the updated one.

I also tried this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) 
{
    super.viewWillAppear(false)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

It still din't work.

Comment: I think you are not updating the array or data which is used to display in your ManualViewController.

Comment: I did update the data, I was able to print the updated data in ManualViewController but not load the updated data in tableview.

Comment: What looks your content in Main.swift like ? Is it an object ? A variable ? A structure ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `NSNotificationCenter` for update your `tableView` from another view.

Your `-addObserver:` declaration has to be like this in your `tableView` Controller in `viewDidLoad` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "refreshTable:", name: "refresh", object: nil)
}
```

And your function for this `addObserver` will like:

```
 func refreshTable(notification: NSNotification) {

    println("Received Notification")
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Now you can post notification like this when you navigate to your `tableView` controller:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("refresh", object: nil, userInfo: nil)
```

Check [THIS](https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/post-notification) sample project for more Info.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Under normal circumstances, the way to update data in a `UITableView` is

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```